# Dificuldade em validar o login

Tags: php, sql, orientação-a-objetos

Tenho este código para uma aplicação de uma loja online mas como sou novo em php estou com alguma dificuldade em validar o login pois ao submeter o form ele aceita tudo o que tiver escrito, existindo o utilizador na base de dados ou não.
O que me está a faltar?

**menu.php:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Menu</title>


<?php
include ("estilos.php");
?>

</head>
<body>

<!-- menu -->
  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <p><img src="imagens/logo.png" height="50px" width="50px"></p>
      <p><h2>LOJA ONLINE LUIS NARCISO</h2></p>
      <li><?php echo "<a href='index.php'> Produtos </a>";?></li>
      <li><?php echo "<a href='carrinho.php'> Carrinho </a>";?></li>
      <li><?php echo "<a href='forum.php'> Fórum </a>";?></li>
      <li><?php echo "<a href='consultas.php'> Consultas </a>";?></li>
      <li><?php echo "<a href='login.php'> Login/Registar </a>";?></li>
      <li><?php
      session_start();
      if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
        echo "<font color='white'>Olá&nbsp&nbsp<b>convidado</font>";
      } else {
        echo "<font color='white'>Olá&nbsp&nbsp<b>".$_SESSION['username']."</b><a href='logout.php'>Logout</a></font>";
      };
      ?></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**login.php:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Carrinho</title>

<?php
include ("menu.php");
?>

</head>
<body>

    <!-- conteudo -->
    <div class="conteudo">
      <p><h1> Login/Registar </h1></p>

        <!-- formulario login -->
        <?php

        if(!isset($_SESSION['username']) ){
          if(!isset($_SESSION['']) and !isset($_SESSION['tentativas'])){
            $_SESSION['codigo']=md5(rand());
            $_SESSION['tentativas']=0;
            $_SESSION['tempo_espera']=0;
          }
          if($_POST){
            $_SESSION['tentativas']++;
            if($_SESSION['tentativas']>10 and $_SESSION['tempo_espera']==0){
              $_SESSION['tempo_espera']=time()+120;
            } else {
              if($_SESSION['codigo']==$_POST['codigo']){
                $conexao = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "loja_online_lnarciso");
                $hash = md5($_POST['password']);
                $query = "SELECT * FROM utilizadores WHERE username = '{$_POST['username']}' and password = '{$hash}'";
                $resultado = mysqli_query($conexao,$query);
                $_SESSION['username']=$_POST['username'];
                header("Location: {$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}");
              } else {
                echo "formulário inválido!</br>";
              }
          }

          } else if($_SESSION['tentativas']<10) {
          ?>

        <form method="POST" action="">
          <table align="center" width="300" border="0">

            <tr>
              <td><label>ENTRAR</label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><label>Username</label></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="username"><br></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><label>Password</label></td>
              <td><input type="password" name="password"><br></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <input type="hidden" name="codigo" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['codigo']; ?>" />
              <td><input type="submit" value="login"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><?php echo "<a href='utilizadores.php'><font color='black'> Registar </a></font>";?></td>
            </tr>

          </table>
        </form>

        <?php }
        if($_SESSION['tempo_espera'] < time() and $_SESSION['tentativas']>10){
          $_SESSION['tempo_espera']=0;
          $_SESSION['tentativas']=0;
        }
      } else {
          echo "<center>Login efetuado com sucesso!</center>";
      }
        ?>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Por que está em uma condiçao apenas **$_POST**, sem nenhuma verificação lógica ?

Answer (score 0):

O código não está de verdade verificando se existe ou não o usuário na tabela. Analisando as seguintes linhas...

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM utilizadores WHERE username = '{$_POST['username']}' and password = '{$hash}'";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexao,$query);
$_SESSION['username']=$_POST['username'];
```

... nota-se que na primeira preparou-se a consulta na tabela; na segunda executou-se a consulta; mas na terceira, indepedente se retornaram ou não dados válidos, **inseriu-se o usuário na sessão**, isto é, foi efetuado o login do usuário.

Você pode testar se retornou uma linha no result set:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM utilizadores WHERE username = '{$_POST['username']}' and password = '{$hash}'";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexao,$query);
// Confere se o validou o usuário
if(mysqli_num_rows($resultado) > 0) // "> 0" não é obrigatório            
    // Efetua o login
    $_SESSION['username']=$_POST['username'];
else
    // Destroy o valor da sessão só para garantir
    unset($_SESSION['username']);
```